# Pycharm complains about using [] operator with pytorch's nn.ModuleList object

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

Pycharm's type-checking complains about the following block of code (taken from [pytorch's docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/container.html#ModuleList)):

```
    import torch.nn as nn
    class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(10, 10) for i in range(10)])

    def forward(self, x):
        # ModuleList can act as an iterable, or be indexed using ints
        for i, l in enumerate(self.linears):
            x = self.linears[i // 2](x) + l(x)
        #                   ^---------- complains here about:
        # Cannot find reference '[' in 'input:(Any, ...), kwargs:dict) -> Any'
        return x
```

Is there a way to fix this issue without suppressing it?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with PyCharm itself. Please submit a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY (and post-back the issue id / link here).

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37601, will be fixed in 2020.1.